# Python find file download link on webpage

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib2

I need a regex that will return to me the text contained between double quotes that starts with a specified text block, and ends with a specific file extension (say .txt).  I'm using urllib2 to get the html of the page (the html is quite simple).

Basically if I have something like

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td>
  <td><a href="Client-8.txt">new_Client-8.txt</a></td>
  <td align="right">27-Jun-2012 18:02  </td>
</tr>
```

It should just return to me

```
Client-8.txt
```

Where the returned value is contained within double quotes.  I know how the file name starts "Client-", and the file extension ".txt".

I'm playing around with r.search(regex, string) where the string I input is the html of the page.  But I stink at regular expressions.

Thanks!

Comment: Time to link my favorite answer on SO again: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/10077

Comment: Well, that put an end to that. Now for something completely different!  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use regular expressions for this task. It's far easier to write a script with [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to process the HTML and to find the element(s) you need.

In your case, you should search for all `<a>` elements whose `href` attribute starts with `Client-` and ends with `.txt`. That will give you a list of all files.

Comment: I've been avoiding using beautifulSoup because I wanted to use only tools included in the basic python package.  But since regex's aren't up to the task I guess I'll have to bite the bullet.  Thanks!

Comment: You can also parse HTML using Python's HTMLParser: http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html . But the code will be longer than using BeautifulSoup (which was made specifically for scraping).

Comment: if you can use external libraries and already know css or jquery selectors pyquery is the best option.  but for this task i would have used just a regex

Answer (score 1):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup('<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/unknown.gif" alt="[   ]"></td><td><a href="Client-8.txt">new_Client-8.txt</a></td><td align="right">27-Jun-2012 18:02  </td>')
x=soup.findAll('a')
for i in x:
    if '.txt' in i['href']:
        print(i['href'])
```